# C++ vector: difference between clear() and resize()

Tags: c++

for a vector

```
std::vector<int> vec;
```

what's the difference between `vec.clear()` and `vec.resize(0)` ?

And if I want to clean a vector, what might be the best practice? (mainly for performance and efficiency concern)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A C++ standard library is allowed to implement `vec.clear()` *as* `vec.resize(0)` so they may well not be distinguishable. Note that neither function is allowed to reduce the *capacity*.

Personally I'd use `clear()` as that ever-so-slightly better signals your intent.